# How to query json file located at s3 using presto

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, presto

I have one json file stored in amazon-s3 location, I want to query this json file using presto. how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you already have Presto running somewhere? What have you tried and what problem are you facing?

Comment: Hi John,

Thank you for your reply 

You can consider array of employee object stored in json format in json file.
Which is output of  some other system and it will going to dump this json file in s3 on daily basis.

I want to query this json file using presto.

Issue. 
 How can I make presto to query this json file stored in s3.

 I tried with location and external_location option available in presto but both are failing, for location I am using full url of s3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 - Presto on EMR with json_extract built-in function**

I am supposing that you have already launched Presto using EMR.

The easiest way to do this would be to use the `json_extract` function that comes by default with Presto.

So imagine you have a json file on s3 like this:

```
{"a": "a_value1", "b": { "bb": "bb_value1" }, "c": "c_value1"}
{"a": "a_value2", "b": { "bb": "bb_value2" }, "c": "c_value2"}
{"a": "a_value3", "b": { "bb": "bb_value3" }, "c": "c_value3"}
...
...
```

Each row represents a json tree object.

So you can simply define in presto a table with one field which is of string type, and then easily query the table with `json_extract`.

```
SELECT json_extract(json_field, '$.b.bb') as extract
FROM my_table
```

The result would be something like:

```
| extract         |
|-----------------|
| bb_value1       |
| bb_value2       |
| bb_value3       |
```

This can be a fast and easy way to read a json file using presto, but unfortunately this doesn't scale well on big json files.

Some presto docs on json_extract: https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_extract

**Option 2 - Presto on EMR with a specific Serde for json files**

You can also customize your presto in bootstrap phase of your emr cluster, by adding custom plugins or SerDe libraries.

So you just have to choose one of the available JSON SerDe libraries (e.g. `org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe`) and follow their guide to define a table that matches the structure of the Json file.

You will be able to access to the fields of the json file in a similar way of the json_extract (using the dotted notation), and it should be faster and scale well on big files. Unfortunately using this method you have 2 main problems:

1) Defining a table for complex files is like being in hell.

2) You may have internal java cast exception, because the data in the json couldn't be easily casted by the SerDe library.

**Option 3 - Athena Built-In JSON Serde**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html

It seems that you have some Json SerDe also built-in Athena, I have personally never tried these but they are managed by AWS so should be easier to set up everything.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain it :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than installing and running your own Presto service, there are some other options you can try:

**Amazon Athena** is a fully-managed Presto service. You can use it to query large datastores in Amazon S3, including compressed and partitioned data.

**Amazon S3 Select** allows you to run a query on a single object stored in Amazon S3. This is possibly simpler for your particular use-case.

Comment: How to configure datastore for presto in my case json file stored in s3 location to select/query this json file. I tried with location and external_location.